# Refudnable payment for new freelancer

Tags: freelance-websites, payment-terms, pay-rate

I am a new freelancer looking for my first client. One employer contacted me through email (after I bid and passed their test)saying I have to pay in their skrill account (as you can see I have copied the exact text). I am bit confused now what to do. Is it a normal thing?

Dear,

Happy to say that you have successfully passed the sample work. Now you can work with us. Before start you have to pay a refundable registration fee of 14.9$ to our skrill account which is X.com . We are taking it for to keep a good relationship with you because we are giving you jobs by taking from our customers. If you didn’t complete the work what we can say for them. That’s why we are taking a refundable registration fee. We will refund it to you after you done your first job.

Answer (score 3):

If it quacks like a duck, walks like a duck, it's probably a duck... In this case, a scam.

First clue should be them asking YOU to pay THEM for YOU to work.

Second clue is the horrendous grammar they are using.

Third, how'd you find these clients? Have you spoken to them in person, or just over email?

This screams SCAM in the loudest possible way. I'd avoid this like the plague.